# What is the difference between datetime.time and time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

What are the differences between datetime.time and time? Both in general and in the context below if I can use one over the other.

I'm looking through some old code written by someone who is no longer at my company.

They have many functions that have their own imports and I'm trying to consolidate all of the imports to the top and I need to know if there are any differences so I can use one over the other or if I need to use both like the original.

```
import datetime
import time

def function1():
  import time
  from time import strptime

def function2():
  from datetime import timedelta
  from datetime import date
  from time import strftime
  from time import strptime
  from time import mktime
  from time import gmtime

def function3():
  from datetime import date
  from time import strptime
  from time import strftime

def function4():
  import time

def main():
  from datetime import date
  from datetime import time
  from time import strptime
```

Comment: [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) is a class in the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)  module which represents times... [`time`] is a module(https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) with various functions related to time (e.g. measuring time).

Comment: IOW, they are different things, and you can't just use one over the other

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hmmmm that's what I thought, I think the implementation of these in the code I'm looking at is confusing me then.